# What does this code mean? Arm assembler

Tags: assembly, arm, reverse-engineering

```
000 LDR             R0, =0x13A3D ; Load from Memory
000 LDR             R1, =0x4000000 ; Load from Memory
000 LDR             R3, =0x400058C ; Load from Memory
000 CMP             R0, R1  ; Set cond. codes on Op1 - Op2
000 BEQ             loc_81B0 ; Branch
```

I'm new in arm and assembler. What does this code mean?

Does it mean "if 0x13A3D==0x4000000 then go to loc_81B0 "? 
It can't be.

Comment: yep, that is what that means.  maybe they are intentionally setting the condition codes knowing it wont branch, or this code is here to prevent reverse engineering, having the branch dest feed into undefined instructions or something else that messes with a disassembler.

Comment: Out of context, sure, but now you need to look for all the _other_ possible codepaths which could end up jumping to that `cmp` with r0 and r1 set differently...

Answer (score 0):

if it's part of a loop, and r0 is being incremented and/or r1 is being decremented, the condition r0 == r1 is what ends the loop.

this assumes the CMP statement is the start of the loop.